# Creating a Regression to see how weather can explain sales development

Tags: regression

In June, a sales representative explained that the weather in Cologne (Germany) has been very rainy and this is causing sales to drop.

Granted, less people go shopping when weather is bad. However, I want to understand how true this statement holds.

- I have Sales per day from our store in Cologne.
- I have Average temperature per day
- I have two dummy variables, Rain (0/1) and Thunder (0/1).

I do the regression in Excel (I lack a statistical software at work).

Here are my results:

```
Regressionsstatistik    
Multiple-R  0,377032755
R-squared   0,142153698
Adj. R-sqr  0,025174657
Std. error  5793,157324
Observations    26
```

From the ANOVA I get this:

```
            df  SS          MS           F  sig. F
Regression  3   122349445,679   40783148,560    1,215   0,328
Residual    22  738334779,230   33560671,783        
Total   25  860684224,908
```

Granted, I have no significance (0.328).

Can I do anything about my data or is the input wrong (shit in, shit out)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shit in = shit out always holds. In this case, I think you could improve a lot by adding more information in your dataset. I'm not sure how many datapoints (days) you have, but adding more features could help.

First, I would try and improve your dataset by looking at how much rain (quantify it!) fell each day and how much of that rain fell within shopping hours. Continuous variables will most likely help better explain the influence than the rain dummy factor. Intuitively, this makes more sense as we're only interested in the rain during those times. Furthermore, allow your model to take into account shopping days (probably a factor). It is likely that people shop more often on certain days, but you don't account for this in your model. Perhaps you have additional information on when your store had sales or holiday sales. After your model, check your model assumptions to see if your model makes any sense (is there even a linear relationship? etc.)

These are some things I could come up with on the spot. Will add more if I think of anything else.

Comment: To further Rogier points, 26 observations is a very small amount for any type of reliable inference. Tracking rain over a few months and therefore adding more observations would allow you to obtain more reliable estimates of both your coefficients and standard errors.

Comment: I missed the number of observations, good point by Antoine. 26 days will never give a good result, I'd get at least 6 months worth of data.

Comment: Thanks, I changed some in the model to mirror what you said. Would you say it's advicable to code it, say for example 1 observation would hold the following information:
1) sales 
2) rain:Y/N 
3) amount of rain 
4) store open: Y/N 
5) amount of store visitors

Comment: In addition to the above, I would add more days, probably 2 whole years, just to get seasonality in to the Picture, but also to be able to tell how and if weather is affecting sales. And at what degree (R-sqr)